# Python asyncio: is the error me or the API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using a third party API Wrapper that supports async. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to use it as I am new to asyncio, and I'm not sure if the errors I'm getting are my usage (most likely) or the wrapper itself.

The API can be found here: https://clashroyale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#royaleapi

The goal of my code is to make three API requests at once (the .get_clan(*lClanGroup)), asynchronously instead of synchronously.

My Code:

```
import clashroyale
import asyncio
import aiohttp

# Define Tokens
unofficialAPIToken = "secretToken"

# Get Client Objects
session1 = aiohttp.ClientSession()
unofficialClient = clashroyale.royaleapi.Client(unofficialAPIToken, session=session1, is_async=True)

lClanGroups = ['PPCLCJG9', '2LRU2J', 'PGLQ0VQ', 'YU2RQG9', '2LVRQ29'],['PYP8UPJV', 'P9L0CYY0', 'Y2RGQPJ', '8P2GYJ8', '9VQJPL2L'],['RYPRGCJ', '809R8PG8', 'PJY9PP98', '2GCQLC', '2GL2QPPL']

async def x(lClanGroup):
    print(*lClanGroup)
    a = await unofficialClient.get_clan(*lClanGroup) # Iterates five tags for the API to request at once
    return a

async def y(lClanGroups):
    result = await asyncio.gather(x(lClanGroups[0]),x(lClanGroups[1]),x(lClanGroups[2]))
    return result

async def close_sessions():
    await session1.close()

asyncio.run(y(lClanGroups))
asyncio.run(close_sessions())
```

The error I'm getting is long and difficult to make sense of:

```
C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Adam/PycharmProjects/ClashRoyaleMeta/testme2.py
PPCLCJG9 2LRU2J PGLQ0VQ YU2RQG9 2LVRQ29
PYP8UPJV P9L0CYY0 Y2RGQPJ 8P2GYJ8 9VQJPL2L
RYPRGCJ 809R8PG8 PJY9PP98 2GCQLC 2GL2QPPL
C:/Users/Adam/PycharmProjects/ClashRoyaleMeta/testme2.py:16: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
  session1 = aiohttp.ClientSession()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Adam/PycharmProjects/ClashRoyaleMeta/testme2.py", line 33, in <module>
    asyncio.run(y(lClanGroups))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 612, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/Users/Adam/PycharmProjects/ClashRoyaleMeta/testme2.py", line 27, in y
    result = await asyncio.gather(x(lClanGroups[0]),x(lClanGroups[1]),x(lClanGroups[2]))
  File "C:/Users/Adam/PycharmProjects/ClashRoyaleMeta/testme2.py", line 23, in x
    a = await unofficialClient.get_clan(*lClanGroup)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\lib\site-packages\clashroyale\royaleapi\client.py", line 203, in _aget_model
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\lib\site-packages\clashroyale\royaleapi\client.py", line 196, in _aget_model
    data, cached, ts, resp = await self._request(url, **params)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\lib\site-packages\clashroyale\royaleapi\client.py", line 150, in _arequest
    async with self.session.get(url, timeout=timeout, headers=self.headers, params=params) as resp:
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 426, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\ClashRoyaleMeta\venv2\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 579, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used '
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000016C5AD50EB0>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Each `asyncio.run()` creates new [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop). Moreover, if you create objects like `aiohttp.ClientSession()` globally, they may be bind to default event loop.

Using multiple event loops in your program is dangerous and may lead to non-obvious problems. To avoid the situation:

- Run `asyncio.run()` only once
- Create all asyncio-related stuff inside main coroutine

---

I didn't work with `royaleapi`, but it seems API developers do things differently than you in their [tests](https://github.com/cgrok/clashroyale/blob/master/tests/royaleapi/test_async.py). Here's how they [innit/close stuff](https://github.com/cgrok/clashroyale/blob/3184c74643ef309c2acb770c7e178b6ef8ab7360/tests/royaleapi/test_async.py#L21) and here's how they [get clan](https://github.com/cgrok/clashroyale/blob/3184c74643ef309c2acb770c7e178b6ef8ab7360/tests/royaleapi/test_async.py#L111).

Let's give it a try?

```
import clashroyale
import asyncio


TOKEN = "secretToken"

clan_groups = [
    ['PPCLCJG9', '2LRU2J', 'PGLQ0VQ', 'YU2RQG9', '2LVRQ29'],
    ['PYP8UPJV', 'P9L0CYY0', 'Y2RGQPJ', '8P2GYJ8', '9VQJPL2L'],
    ['RYPRGCJ', '809R8PG8', 'PJY9PP98', '2GCQLC', '2GL2QPPL']
]


async def get_clans(cr, clan_groups):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[
        cr.get_clan(tag)
        for group in clan_groups
        for tag in group
    ])


async def main():
    cr = clashroyale.RoyaleAPI(
        TOKEN, 
        is_async=True,
        timeout=30
    )
    try:
        results = await get_clans(cr, clan_groups)
        print(results)
    finally:
        await cr.close()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Didn't test it.

Comment: Code successfully gets the results for all 15 clan tags, but then throws an error "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed." when the script completes. Complete error log: https://pastebin.com/5FdXjX41

Comment: @user2460638 in tests [they do](https://github.com/cgrok/clashroyale/blob/3184c74643ef309c2acb770c7e178b6ef8ab7360/tests/royaleapi/test_async.py#L25) `await asyncio.sleep(2)` right after `await cr.close()`. It probably needed for some background cleanups. Try to alter the code same way.

Comment: Mikhail, that works! Unfortunately it's taking a variable length of sleep time. Any way to wait for a specific item to clean up?
Additionally, it's still throwing this error code no matter how long I wait:
https://pastebin.com/mSQ57Dz2